# iOS Facebook Api, make a like to a comment post

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-comments

I want to like a comment of a post on Facebook, I use the same as like the post. For like a post, it works, but for like a comment fail.

**Doc**:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/likes

**My Code**:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/likes", postId_]
                             parameters:nil
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
                        {  //Error:
                        }];
```

**The Error is**:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)" UserInfo=0x158999b0 {com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode=400, com.facebook.sdk:ParsedJSONResponseKey={
>       body =     {
>           error =         {
>               code = 100;
>               message = "(#100) Error finding the requested story";
>               type = OAuthException;
>           };
>       };
>       code = 400;
>   }, com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey=}

Comment: Well this should work. Either the comment's id is incorrect or the user is not authorized to like the comment. The later seems not be the case since you are creating comment using the same user. You can check the same in [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) it works!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it, and it works like a charm

```
    // post is my module object, encapsulates the info form the post
    // pass the post ID
    NSString *graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/likes", post.postID];

    FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:graphPath];
    // DELETE or POST the like
    NSString *method = post.liked?@"DELETE":@"POST";
    [request setHTTPMethod:method];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        BOOL success = YES;
        success = (error)?NO:YES;
        if(success) {

        }
    }];
```

Note: make sure you have publish permissions

Comment: It seems that the permissions are ok, because it's the same permission to like a simple post, isn't it? remember, i don't want to like a simple post (it works great for me), i want to like a comment that have been done at the post. (the post_id it's the post_id of the comment at the post.)

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use the following code:

```
NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:URL, @"object", nil];

  if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.accessTokenData.accessToken) {
      [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes"
                                   parameters:params
                                   HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                            completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                              NSLog(@"Just liked on Facebook!");
                            }];
    } else NSLog(@"Cannot open FBSession");
  }
```

There no code for opening or initializing FBSession - I hope, it's not a problem?

Comment: This code make a like of a Facebook comment post? Where is the Facebook comment post id?

Answer (score 0):

I think, we all can trust Facebook, yes? :)

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes, select "IOS SDK" tab and look at the code.